# How to space evenly items in a row

Tags: android, leanback

I'm working on an Android TV app (using leanback) and I'm having some difficulties implementing a row that has 4 items. The items should be evenly distributed across the row and it should not scroll.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGX2J.png).

How can I implement it ?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `VerticalGridSupportFragment`?